# Add content of a table into an array using DOMDocument

Tags: php, xpath, domdocument, domxpath

I have `$html`:

```
$html = '
<table id="myTable">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>08/20/18</td>
            <td> <a href="https://example.com/1a">Text 1 A</a> </td>
            <td> <a href="https://example.com/1b">Test 1 B</a> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>08/21/18</td>
            <td> <a href="https://example.com/2a">Text 2 A</a> </td>
            <td> <a href="https://example.com/2b">Test 2 B</a> </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
';
```

Using [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php), I want to add the content of the table into a multidimensional `$array`:

```
$array = array(
    // tr 1
    array(
        array(
            'content' => '08/20/18'
        ),
        array(
            'content' => 'Text 1 A',
            'href' => 'https://example.com/1a'
        ),
        array(
            'content' => 'Text 1 B',
            'href' => 'https://example.com/1b'
        )
    ),
    // tr 2
    array(
        array(
            'content' => '08/21/18'
        ),
        array(
            'content' => 'Text 2 A',
            'href' => 'https://example.com/1a'
        ),
        array(
            'content' => 'Text 2 B',
            'href' => 'https://example.com/1b'
        )
    )
);
```

### What I've tried so far

I've managed to get the content of the `table` using `xpath`:

```
// setup DOMDocument
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="utf-8" ?>' . $html); 
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
// target table using xpath
$results = $xpath->query("//*[@id='myTable']");

if ($results->length > 0) {
    var_dump($results->item(0));
    var_dump($results->item(0)->nodeValue);
}
```

[Test it](https://3v4l.org/MYUdP). What is the approach to put the content of each `tr` into the `$array`?

Comment: Lovely! Every question on this site should have a *what i've tried so far* section. +1

Comment: I will add a 50 point bounty when this question is eligible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$html = '
<table id="myTable">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>08/20/18</td>
            <td> <a href="https://example.com/1a">Text 1 A</a> </td>
            <td> <a href="https://example.com/1b">Test 1 B</a> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>08/21/18</td>
            <td> <a href="https://example.com/2a">Text 2 A</a> </td>
            <td> <a href="https://example.com/2b">Test 2 B</a> </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
';

$data = [];

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="utf-8" ?>' . $html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$trs = $xpath->query("//*[@id='myTable']/tbody/tr");
foreach ($trs as $i => $tr) {
    /** @var DOMElement $td */
    foreach ($tr->childNodes as $td) {
        if ($td instanceof DOMElement) {
            /** @var DOMElement $a */
            $row = [];
            foreach ($td->childNodes as $a) {
                /** @var DOMAttr $attribute */
                $row['content'] = $td->nodeValue;
                if ($a->hasAttributes()) {
                    foreach ($a->attributes as $attribute) {
                        $row[$attribute->name] = $attribute->value;
                    }

                }

            }
            $data[$i][] = $row;
        }
    }
}

var_dump($data);
```

Comment: Thanks! I am testing this but it is throwing warnings, please see [this](https://3v4l.org/6cZfR).

Comment: look at modified version

Answer (score 1):

This looked interesting so i gave it a try.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$multidimensional_array = [];
$i = 0;
$myTable = $dom->getElementById('myTable');
foreach ($myTable->getElementsByTagName('tr') as $tableRow) {
   foreach ($tableRow->getElementsByTagName('td') as $tableData) {

        foreach ($tableData->getElementsByTagName('a') as $a) {
            $href = ($a->getAttribute('href'));
        }

        if(isset($href) && !empty($href)){
            $multidimensional_array[$i][] = array(
                                                'content'   => $tableData->nodeValue,
                                                'href'      => $href
                                            );
            unset($href);
        }else{
            $multidimensional_array[$i][] = array(
                                                'content'   => $tableData->nodeValue
                                                );
        }

   }
   $i++;
}
print_r($multidimensional_array);
```

Hope it is what was asked.

Edit: added the specific table search before the loops.

Comment: Interesting! But can you target the specific table, similar to what I did `$xpath->query("//*[@id='myTable']");`. Your approach targets every single `tr` and `td`. =)

Comment: You can get the specific table by searching it's Id.
Added this into my answer.